# Can I use Flutter with an embedded graph database preferably using Gremlin (Apache TinkerPop)?

Tags: flutter, dart, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm wondering what options are out there for a mobile app written in Flutter to preferably embed and use a local graph database like Bitsy or any other Gremlin/Apache TinkerPop compatible graph database, so that the user can still use the app offline. Ideally, there should be an online sync, but graph queries should work offline, too (assuming the data is manageable on a mobile phone). Dart isn't even there in the list of supported languages on the Apache TinkerPop page: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/community.html

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it but I don't think it is possible. I"m not aware of a Gremlin Language Variant for Dart and apart from this question I don't think I've seen a request for this support. Also, If you need local graph database you would need to run Gremlin Server hosting your graph on the mobile device.  That basically means getting the entire TinkerPop stack on android/ios and forgetting ios for a moment, if I recall correctly there may or may not be problems with certain TinkerPop modules on android - I believe folks have brought that up before but I can't recall the exact problems. In short, trying to make this work is probably going to be a bit of an uphill battle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately you confirmed my suspicion.